# Accessing MR job output from java main class

Tags: hadoop, jobs

My MapReduce program has three chained MR jobs. I want to access MR1 ouptut from the main class. Is it possible in hadoop environment?

If not, then please suggest if there is any other way to do similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to feed the output of job 1 to input of job2 and output of job2 to input of job3.

Here is an example how: http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#chaining

This blog talks about some more:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/03/29/how-to-chain-multiple-mapreduce-jobs-in-hadoop.aspx